# An urn has 2 white, 3 red and 5 black balls. Problem

Tags: probability

An urn has 2 white, 3 red and 5 black balls. 3 balls are randomly drawn, one at a time and without replacement.

Calculate the probability of extracting the sequence of colors (white, black, red) knowing that you have extracted a black ball.

**solution**

Let E be the event that refers to the indicated color sequence. The required probability is $P(E|X= 1)$ from which it follows $P(E|X= 1) = \frac{P(E⋂(X=1))}{P(X=1)} = \frac{P(E)}{P(X=1)} \overset{(question1)}{=} \frac{\frac{2}{10}\frac{5}{9}\frac{3}{8}}{\frac{5}{12}} = \frac{\frac{1}{24}}{\frac{5}{12}} = \frac{1}{10}$

**question 1**
If the sequence is (white, black, red) in the numerator we should not have: $\frac{3}{10}\frac{5}{9}\frac{2}{8}$ in the end the result is the same but surely the reasoning to obtain it is different.What can be the reasoning done in the solution?

And in the denominator , why $\frac{5}{12}$. $P(X=1)$ indicates the probability that a black ball has been extracted. This shouldn't be $\frac{5}{10}$

Comment: What you wrote is hard to follow.  The numerator is $\frac 2{10}\times \frac 59\times \frac 38$ as written in your "solution".  in your "question $1$" you switched the $2$ and $3$ for some reason.  Doesn't change the value, of course.  And the denominator isn't $\frac 5{10}$....where did that come from?

Comment: For denominator, you say probability is 5/10. 5/10 is the probability to have a black ball at a specific place. Here we know :  knowing that you have extracted a black ball.  This should be clarified ; is it : knowing that you have extracted at least a black ball or knowing that you have extracted exactly a black ball

Comment: I don't know what your variable $X$ means, you ought to define it.  The probability that at least one black ball has been drawn is $1-\binom 53\big/ \binom {10}3=\frac {11}{12}$.

Comment: The probability that *exactly* one black ball has been drawn is $3\times \frac 5{10}\times \frac 59\times \frac 48=\frac 5{12}$.  You never stated whether you were looking at the event "*at least one* black ball is drawn" or the event "*exactly* one black ball is drawn".  These give different results.

Comment: @lulu I would interpret the question as written as extracting at least one ball.

Comment: I'm confused by what OP's question is here. Please could you clarify, OP ?

Comment: @AdamRobinson Why? Could be either. The numerical value provided matches *exactly*. But the OP's post is vague and hard to follow, so who knows?

Comment: the exercise says :"...knowing that you have drawn a black ball". I think it means exactly one. Especially since in the solution there is this writing $P(E|X= 1)$ and I interpret X as the variable that counts the number of black balls extracted from the urn. The doubt about the denominator is if the X indicates the variable just written, P(X=1) is the probability that exactly one ball will be extracted. But since there are 5 black ones and in all there are 10 balls. Isn't the probability of extracting exactly one black one 5/10?

Comment: @lulu why do you write "...that exactly one black ball has been drawn is " $3*\frac{5}{10}*\frac{5}{9}*\frac{4}{8}=\frac{5}{12}$

Comment: There are $3$ times you can draw the one black ball, each of the three is equally likely.  The probability that you first draw a black ball is $\frac 5{10}$.  Now,   given that you have drawn a black ball first, the probability that the second draw is non-black is $\frac 59$, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Start by computing the probability of drawing a black ball. The probability that *no* black ball is drawn is $\frac{1}{2} \frac{4}{9} \frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{12}$. Therefore, the probability that a black ball is drawn is $1 - \frac{1}{12} = \frac{11}{12}$.

Now, compute the probability of observing the sequence (white, black, red). This is straightforward: $\frac{1}{5} \frac{5}{9} \frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{24}$.

The desired conditional probability is thus $\frac{\frac{1}{24}}{\frac{11}{12}} = \boxed{\frac{1}{22}}$.

Edit: Suppose that instead of "a black ball", we are interested in the condition that "exactly one black ball" is drawn. For this, consider that the number of permutations of three selected balls (regardless of color, and assuming they are distinguishable) is $(10) (9) (8) = 720$. To extract exactly one black ball, we must select it among $5$ choices, and choose one position out of $3$ possible. Then, for the first unselected position, we choose one of the $5$ non-black balls, and for the last position, we choose one of the $4$ remaining non-black balls. The number of ways is $(5) (3) (5) (4) = 300$. The probability of extracting *exactly* one black ball is thus $\frac{300}{720} = \frac{5}{12}$. And the desired conditional probability would be $\frac{\frac{1}{24}}{\frac{5}{24}} = \boxed{\frac{1}{10}}$.

Comment: I see. I'll update my answer to account for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Total Universe is $10 \times 9 \times 8 =720$

Part of universe is excluded : we know that at least one ball is black. So all combinations based on only Red+White are excluded : $5 \times 4 \times 3 =60$ combinations are excluded.

So Universe is reduced to $720-60=660$

Number of combinations that match with sequence (White,Black,Red) is $2 \times 5 \times 3= 30$

So, probability is $\frac {30}{660}=\frac{1}{22}$

Conditional probability means that you will divide a fraction by another fraction. It is too complex. It is easier to divide an integer (count of success) by another integer (size of restricted universe).